# How to have different text overflow style in DropdownButton in hint text and in the DropdownMenuItem in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-dropdownbutton

I want to set the overflow of hint text of DropdownButton to ellipsis, but I want to show the whole choice in the DropdownMenuItem when I open the dropdown list, so I set it to visible
But what happens is that the hint text gets the "visible" effect despite that I set it to ellipsis, How can I fix this?

What I want to happen:

[image]
[image]

What happens:

[image]
[image]

Here is the code

```
Expanded(
            child: DropdownButton(
              hint: Text(
                widget.choices[0],
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              iconSize: 40,
              isExpanded: true,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onChanged: changeValueFunction,
              items: widget.choices
                  .map(
                    (value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(
                        value,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                        style: TextStyle(
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: try  selectedItemBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

> selectedItemBuilder

to draw custom item